# Collision detection in nuxt.js. code is running without errors. But some functionalities not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, collision-detection

I am working with collision detection in vue.js using nuxt.js framework. I have done a similar program from this source
https://codepen.io/dropinks/pen/MrzPXB

I have converted this js code in vue friendly template and script. Only problem is that the the collision is not being detected . Please take a look at my code and tell where i made mistake.

Here is the link for codesandbox online editor where i have the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-hill-466s7?file=/pages/index.vue

template code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rectangle-1" id="rect">Hover Me</div>
    <div class="rectangle-2" id="dragMe">Drag Me</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

styles:

```
<style scoped>
container {
  position: relative;
}
.rectangle-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.rectangle-1.collide {
  background: #EF5350;
}
.rectangle-1:after {
  content: ":-)";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.rectangle-1.collide:after {
  content: ":-(";
}
.rectangle-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #F5B041;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: move;
  transition: 0.5s box-shadow ease, 0.5s transform ease;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.rectangle-2.onDrag {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate(-3px, -3px);
}
</style>
```

script

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dragMe: "",
      rect: "",
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    if (process.client) {
      this.myFunction();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    myFunction: function () {
      this.rect = document.getElementById("rect");
      this.dragMe = document.getElementById("dragMe");

      this.initDrag({
        element: this.dragMe,
        drag: function () {
          this.isCollapsed(this.dragMe, this.rect);
        },
      });
    },

    isCollapsed: function (dragMe, rect) {
      var object_1 = this.dragMe.getBoundingClientRect();
      var object_2 = this.rect.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (
        object_1.left < object_2.left + object_2.width &&
        object_1.left + object_1.width > object_2.left &&
        object_1.top < object_2.top + object_2.height &&
        object_1.top + object_1.height > object_2.top
      ) {
        rect.classList.add("collide");
        document.getElementById('dragMe').style.background = 'blue';
      } else {
        rect.classList.remove("collide");
      }
    },

    initDrag: function (options) {
      var element = options.element;
      var mousedown,
        mouseup,
        mousemove,
        dragStart,
        initX,
        initY,
        offsetLeft,
        offsetTop;

      function mouseMove(ev) {
        if (dragStart) {
          var newX = offsetLeft + (ev.pageX - initX);
          var newY = offsetTop + (ev.pageY - initY);

          element.style.top = newY + "px";
          element.style.left = newX + "px";

          options.drag.call();
        }
      }

      function mouseUp(ev) {
        dragStart = false;
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);

        options.stop.call();
      }

      function mouseDown(ev) {
        initX = ev.pageX;
        initY = ev.pageY;
        dragStart = true;
        offsetLeft = element.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop = element.offsetTop;
        document.addEventListener(
          "mousemove",
          function (ev) {
            mouseMove(ev);
          },
          false
        );
        document.addEventListener(
          "mouseup",
          function (ev) {
            mouseUp(ev);
          },
          false
        );

        options.start.call();
      }

      element.addEventListener(
        "mousedown",
        function (ev) {
          mouseDown(ev);
        },
        false
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```